# UIPasteboard analog for Android

Tags: android, ios

On ios I use UIPasteBoard to store id of client which is generated first time user start app, the data stored in UIPasteBoard is there event when you remove and reinstall app. Is there storage with the same functionality on Android. Thanks

Comment: See Intent https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/index.html

Comment: How you propose to implement functionality I`ve writed later with intents? Intent send data to another app or start another activity of the same one. I need ability to get data after the app was totaly removed and reinstalled!

Comment: intent is used to start activity from same app or from other. You do not need to have the target application started.  You can have an example with Tasker and Trigger : Trigger get Tasker task from Intent. So you can get and send data with Intent. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20740062/1377145

Comment: It`s not the same functionality. I have a method in with by get I`m getting id I saved last time. how intent can help me?

Comment: SharedPreferenses partialy solves the problem due to removing data when app is removed

Comment: Ho, sorry the the misunderstanding, SharedPreferences is a partial solution, see http://blog.grapefruitopia.com/post/18755719222/backing-up-and-restoring-a-users for saving it to DataStorage. The best way should be to have an online database and syncing the data when user re-install the app

Comment: To sync something you have to know some id key of this user. That`s why i`m looking for UIpasteBoard analog

Comment: See this answer so http://stackoverflow.com/a/5626208/1377145